# Sample Space Size for unit interval [0,1] Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, cardinals

What is the sample space size for a set like ${(x,y)∈[0,1]^2}$? Should it be infinite? Since there are infinite members of this set so the cardinality is uncountably infinite. Similarly, what is the sample space size for the unit interval sample space $∈ [0,1]$?

Is there a definition for defining this kind of sample space size?

The reason I am asking for this is calculating $P=|A|/|$sample space$|$, $A$ being event space. if sample space$=\\{(x,y)∈[0,1]^2|x ≥ y\\}$, $A=\\{(x,y)∈[0,1]^2| x ≥ 1/2,y ≤ 1/2,x ≤ y + 1/2\\}$, then $P=1/4$ but since both are infinite we just calculate the areas of the two spaces, how do we know the event space and the sample space have the same density on average (occupied by $(x,y)$ points)?

Comment: I don't really understand. If it comes to uniform distribution on $[0,1]^2$ then you can use $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ as [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space) and the collection of Borel subsets of $\Omega$ as [event space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(probability_theory)). In this setting you don't work with $P(A)=|A|/|\Omega|$ for events $A$ because that only works if $\Omega$ is finite. Here we work with $P(A)=\iint1_Adxdy$

Comment: so am i right about the cardinality of sample space and event space ehre both being infinite? like P=1/4 does not mean sample space size is 4 and event space size is 1; if thats the case how can infinite size/infinite size equal to 1/4? please show me how you use the formula of double integral you mentioned in the later example i provided

Comment: notice if i use your formula the P=1/8 instead because sample space is not [0,1]^2 in my example but theres a restriction of x>=y which makes the P=1/4 and your formula wont work

Comment: Is your sample space $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\mid x\geq y\}$ (so not $[0,1]^2$)? then the probability of some event $A\subset\Omega$ equals $2\iint1_Adxdy$. This because there is a constant pdf that takes value $2=1/\iint1_{\Omega}dxdy$. You could also say $P(A)=\frac{\iint1_Adxdy}{\iint1_{\Omega}dxdy}$

Answer (score 1):

Let it be that $X,Y$ are random variables that have a joint probability  uniform on $\Omega:=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in[0,1]^2\mid x\geq y\}$.

Uniformity is characterized by a **constant** PDF $f$ on $\Omega$ that satisfies: $$\iint_{\Omega}f(x,y)dxdy=\mathsf P(\Omega)=1$$Substituting $f(x,y)=c$ in this we find that $\frac12c=1$ or equivalently that $c=2$

So the distribution is determined by PDF $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto2$ if $\langle x,y\rangle\in\Omega$ and $\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto0$ otherwise.

Then for any event $A\subseteq\Omega$ we find:$$\mathsf P(A)=2\iint_Adxdy$$

This can be applied on $A=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in[0,1]^2\mid x\geq 1/2\text{ and }y\leq 1/2\text{ and }x\leq y + 1/2\}\subseteq\Omega$.